# How to bypass RemoveDir target command in MSBuild configuration?

Tags: msbuild

I want to remove a couple of directories in my build process. But if for any reason, they can not be deleted, I want to ignore the error and move on.

I know I can use [`RemoveDir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/removedir-task?view=vs-2019) for this purpose. But I don't know how to tell to ignore errors and does not break the build.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ContinueOnError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-ignore-errors-in-tasks?view=vs-2019)-attribute on the `RemoveDir`-task. You get to choose what should happen in case `RemoveDir` cannot do its job.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="RemoveDirectories">
        <RemoveDir ContinueOnError="WarnAndContinue"
            Directories="$(SomeDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Note that the `ContinueOnError`-attribute is not specific to the `RemoveDir`-task. You can use it on others as well.

If for some reason this isn't enough, you can always bail out into the OS.
For example, use this instead of the `RemoveDir`-task to not have any warning at all.

```
<Exec Command="cmd.exe /c rmdir &quot;$(SomeDir)&quot; 2&gt;NUL" IgnoreExitCode="true"/>
```

Mind you that this is not platform independent. If your build needs to run on other OSs than Windows, you need to detect and adjust accordingly.